# Android get the value of edittext after the user ends typing

Tags: android, android-edittext

I would like to get the value of edittext after the user ends typing. So the default is, the edittext is empty. It has no value in it. After the user inputs a value, it should get it.

This is what I've tried:

```
     etQuantity.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Log.d("Quantity", s_quantity);

                int i_quantity = Integer.parseInt(s_quantity);
                int i_grossAmount = i_quantity * i_sellingPrice;
                etGrossAmount.setText(String.valueOf(i_grossAmount));
                Log.d("Gross Amount", "" + String.valueOf(i_grossAmount));


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }     
    });
```

But it doesn't get the correct value I input. Any ideas? Help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: tyr to use keycodes event.keyup,event.keydown  to solve this

Comment: @nikhil can you give some codes to do that? Thanks

Comment: `But it doesn't get the correct value I input.` What does it get, and what do you consider to be the 'correct value'. Can you please be more specific with what you are looking to achieve?

Comment: @FoamyGuy It just gets a null.

Comment: What is "it"? And what is s_quantity? And what do you expect to get when not using the 'Editable'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

its a quick work try it out hope it helps

```
EditText text = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
text.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("ONtext changed " + new String(s.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("beforeTextChanged " + new String(s.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("afterTextChanged " + new String(s.toString()));
        }
    });
```

Comment: this will print out after each letter user types

Answer (score 2):

```
final EditText et = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "" + et.getText().toString(), 2000).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Try this code...